# Does a TCP socket connection have a "keep alive"?

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp, keep-alive

I have heard of HTTP keep-alive but for now I want to open a socket connection with a remote server.
Now will this socket connection remain open forever or is there a timeout limit associated with it similar to HTTP keep-alive?

Comment: Just to make sure "http keepalive" is typically not related to socket keepalive, it talks about the HTTP/1.1 feature of keeping connections open for further requests. It is only related to TCP keepalive as it needs to detect broken TCP connections (or normally only keeps the sockets open for limited time).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

TCP sockets remain open till they are closed.

That said, it's very difficult to detect a broken connection (broken, as in a router died, etc, as opposed to closed) without actually sending data, so most applications do some sort of ping/pong reaction every so often just to make sure the connection is still actually alive.

Comment: Okay so the implementation should make sure to check at regular interval that the connection is dead or alive, right?

Comment: It's a good idea. You don't *have* to, but if you don't, then you may not detect a broken link till someone actually wants to do something. Which may or may not be a good thing (or may or may not matter), depending on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @MatthewScharley What's the usual request/response used for ping/pong?

Comment: @Pacerier: Depends on the protocol, since it's totally protocol dependent, but for text-based protocols that require one literal "PING" and "PONG" commands are pretty typical.

Comment: @MatthewScharley : This "ping pong" is already implemented for us, in the standard TCP implementations, and is called "keep-alive" (see the other popular answer to this question).  Is there some reason to implement it at the app level?

Comment: @TimCooper: It's isn't really. As I highlighted in comments on other answers, the TCP implementation isn't useful for most *application* level requirements. You can't send one on demand, and for most operating systems the TCP keepalive timeout is only configurable on a system-wide level and set far too high to be generally useful for applications.

Comment: @Tim The reason for an keep-alive on application level is that the TCP standard recommends to set the keep-alive timer to higher than two hours. Never seen an TCP connection without traffic that survives this time. Hence the TCP keep-alive stuff is useless by default.

Comment: How does one do ping-pong check ?

Comment: @Robert No it doesn't. It states that the *default* may not be *less than* two hours.

Answer (score 190):

> Does a TCP socket connection have a "keep alive"?

The short answer is **yes** there is a timeout enforced via *TCP Keep-Alive*, so no the socket won't remain open forever but will probably time out after a few *hours*.

If you would like to configure the Keep-Alive timeout on your machine, see the "Changing TCP Timeouts" section below. Otherwise read through the rest of the answer to learn how TCP Keep-Alive works.

## Introduction

TCP connections consist of two sockets, one on each end of the connection. When one side wants to terminate the connection, it sends an `FIN` packet which the other side acknowledges and both close their sockets.

Until that happens, however, both sides will keep their socket open indefinitely. This leaves open the possibility that one side may close their socket, either intentionally or due to some error, without informing the other end via `FIN`. In order to detect this scenario and close stale connections the TCP Keep Alive process is used.

## Keep-Alive Process

There are three configurable properties that determine how Keep-Alives work. On Linux they are<sup>1</sup>:

- `tcp_keepalive_time`

  - default 7200 seconds
- `tcp_keepalive_probes`

  - default 9
- `tcp_keepalive_intvl`

  - default 75 seconds

The process works like this:

1. Client opens TCP connection
2. If the connection is silent for `tcp_keepalive_time` seconds, send a single empty `ACK` packet.<sup>1</sup>
3. Did the server respond with a corresponding `ACK` of its own?

   - **No**

     1. Wait `tcp_keepalive_intvl` seconds, then send another `ACK`
     2. Repeat until the number of `ACK` probes that have been sent equals `tcp_keepalive_probes`.
     3. If no response has been received at this point, send a `RST` and terminate the connection.
   - **Yes**: Return to step 2

This process is enabled by default on most operating systems, and thus dead TCP connections are regularly pruned once the other end has been unresponsive for 2 hours 11 minutes (7200 seconds + 75 * 9 seconds).

## Gotchas

### 2 Hour Default

Since the process doesn't start until a connection has been idle for two hours by default, stale TCP connections can linger for a very long time before being pruned. This can be especially harmful for expensive connections such as database connections.

### Keep-Alive is Optional

According to [RFC 1122 4.2.3.6](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1122/114.htm), responding to and/or relaying TCP Keep-Alive packets *is optional*:

> Implementors MAY include "keep-alives" in their TCP implementations,
> although this practice is not universally accepted. If keep-alives are
> included, the application MUST be able to turn them on or off for each
> TCP connection, and they MUST default to off.

> ...

> It is extremely
> important to remember that ACK segments that contain no data are not
> reliably transmitted by TCP.

The reasoning being that Keep-Alive packets contain no data and are not strictly necessary and risk clogging up the tubes of the interwebs if overused.

*In practice however*, my experience has been that this concern has dwindled over time as bandwidth has become cheaper; and thus Keep-Alive packets are not usually dropped. [Amazon EC2 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html) for instance gives an indirect endorsement of Keep-Alive, so if you're hosting with AWS you are likely safe relying on Keep-Alive, but your mileage may vary.

## Changing TCP Timeouts

### Per Socket

**2022 Update:** *Apparently, [as of Java 11, you may be able to set these on the Java TCP Socket itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067335/446554)*

Unfortunately since TCP connections are managed on the OS level, older versions of Java do not support configuring timeouts on a per-socket level such as in `java.net.Socket`. I have found some attempts<sup>3</sup> to use Java Native Interface (JNI) to create Java sockets that call native code to configure these options, but none appear to have widespread community adoption or support.

Instead, you may be forced to apply your configuration to the operating system as a whole. Be aware that this configuration will affect all TCP connections running on the entire system.

### Linux

The currently configured TCP Keep-Alive settings can be found in

- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time`
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes`
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl`

You can update any of these like so:

```
# Send first Keep-Alive packet when a TCP socket has been idle for 3 minutes
$ echo 180 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
# Send three Keep-Alive probes...
$ echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
# ... spaced 10 seconds apart.
$ echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
```

Such changes will not persist through a restart. To make persistent changes, use `sysctl`:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=180 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=10
```

### Mac OS X

The currently configured settings can be viewed with `sysctl`:

```
$ sysctl net.inet.tcp | grep -E "keepidle|keepintvl|keepcnt"
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000
net.inet.tcp.keepcnt: 8
```

Of note, Mac OS X defines `keepidle` and `keepintvl` in units of milliseconds as opposed to Linux which uses seconds.

The properties can be set with `sysctl` which will persist these settings across reboots:

```
sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.keepidle=180000 net.inet.tcp.keepcnt=3 net.inet.tcp.keepintvl=10000
```

Alternatively, you can add them to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (creating the file if it doesn't exist).

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
net.inet.tcp.keepidle=180000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl=10000
net.inet.tcp.keepcnt=3
```

### Windows

I don't have a Windows machine to confirm, but you should find the respective TCP Keep-Alive settings in the registry at

`\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters`

<sub>*Footnotes*</sub>

<sub>1. See `man tcp` for more information.</sub>

<sub>2.  This packet is often referred to as a "Keep-Alive" packet, but within the TCP specification it is just a regular `ACK` packet. Applications like Wireshark are able to label it as a "Keep-Alive" packet by meta-analysis of the sequence and acknowledgement numbers it contains in reference to the preceding communications on the socket.</sub>

<sub>3. Some examples I found from a basic Google search are [lucwilliams/JavaLinuxNet](https://github.com/lucwillems/JavaLinuxNet) and [flonatel/libdontdie](https://github.com/flonatel/libdontdie).</sub>

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! One addition: For Windows a restart is required in order to have new values of KeepAliveTime being effective.

Comment: On AIX, current TCP Keep-Alive settings can be queried using `$ no -a | grep tcp_keep` command.

Comment: When a TCP socket  is created, it can be created with  keepalive values other than default.  
Does anyone know how to find the keepalive value for a running process?  

I have looked in /proc/PID/net/netstat, but the value found there is not useful, or at least, I cannot find an explanation for it.

Comment: In my opinion, the term "alive" is misleading. After all: asserting that a connection is "alive" only means that you have performed some form of _successful communication_ (past tense!), but it will be *no guarantee* that any or all subsequent communication will succeed (present/future tense). Therefore there really is no merit in doing this at *neither* the TCP level *nor* at the application level, and you're much better off deciding for either a robust _retry-on-failure_ or a _crash-my-app_ approach than any other false sense of security which most people are probably looking for.

Comment: A TCP connection is terminated by exchanging FINs, not RSTs. RST is an abortive close and it is not acknowledged.

Comment: Looks like Java 11 now has extended socket options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472844/how-to-set-socket-option-tcp-keepcnt-tcp-keepidle-tcp-keepintvl-in-java-or-n

Answer (score 57):

You are looking for the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option.

The [Java Socket API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) exposes "keep-alive" to applications via the `setKeepAlive` and `getKeepAlive` methods.

EDIT: SO_KEEPALIVE is implemented in the OS network protocol stacks without sending any "real" data.  The keep-alive interval is operating system dependent, and may be tuneable via a kernel parameter.

Since no data is sent, SO_KEEPALIVE can only test the liveness of the network connection, not the liveness of the service that the socket is connected to.  To test the latter, you need to implement something that involves sending messages to the server and getting a response.

Comment: If I a setKeepAlive(true); what would be the interval?... also will Java keep sending keep-alive messages at the default interval or will I have to do it programatically?

Comment: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.7.shtml Has a description of SO_KEEPALIVE. It's not so much what the OP wanted, though it *is* a protocol based option to what I suggested... though, once every two hours won't do much for applications.

Comment: @MatthewScharley Isn't the interval configurable?

Comment: @Pacerier: It's supposed to be, but it's usually at the OS level not an application level. It's also usually not exposed very cleanly or obviously. The TCP spec also specifies that it must not be allowed to be set less than 2 hours, hence my comment.

Comment: @MatthewScharley Regarding "it must not **default** to no less than two hours"... means it is allowed to be less than two hours right?

Comment: @Pacerier: You're right, but that'd be implementation specific and I have no first-hand experience to know if you can in practice. Also note my previous comment that it's usually an OS level setting, so by changing it you are affecting every other application running. You likely don't want keep-alives on a short interval across the board.

Comment: @MatthewScharley - *"You're right, but that'd be implementation specific ..."*.  A keep-alive interval that could not be less than two hours would be so useless that it is hard to conceive of anyone implementing it.

Comment: For linux, [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) has instructions for changing the keepalive time (which defaults to 2h).

Comment: @Daniel - it should be noted that if you are using Java, those instructions only allow you to change the system-wide default for the keep-alive interval.  That is rather heavy handed ...

Comment: @StephenC, I realize that changing the system setting isn't a great solution, but what's the alternative? AFAIK there's no way for an application to override the system setting.

Comment: @Daniel - the alternative (in Java) would be to do *manual* keep alive, as mentioned above and in other answers.  Not pretty, but it *maybe* better than an OS-wide change of the default that *could* break system services or other applications.

Answer (score 36):

TCP keepalive and HTTP keepalive are very different concepts. In TCP, the keepalive is the administrative packet sent to detect stale connection. In HTTP, keepalive means the persistent connection state.

This is from TCP specification,

*Keep-alive packets MUST only be sent when no data or acknowledgement packets have been received for the connection within an interval. This interval MUST be configurable and MUST default to no less than two hours.*

As you can see, the default TCP keepalive interval is too long for most applications. You might have to add keepalive in your application protocol.

Comment: You can modify the TCP keepalive interval to suit your application. E.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877220%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @ZZCoder Can you elaborate what does it mean when you say "In HTTP, keepalive means the persistent connection state"?

Comment: @Pacerier: In `HTTP/1.0` each request/response necessitated reconnecting to the server. For `HTTP/1.1` they introduced a `Keep-Alive` header which could be used to trigger the server to not kill the connection after it was done processing the response to facilitate requesting more files and allowing for 'pipelining'; sending multiple requests then waiting for all the data to come back.

Comment: It basically means that many HTTP request will/should reuse the same TCP-Connection (These connections might also have keep-alive but that doesn't meter to HTTP so it's essentially a different concept).

Answer (score 25):

If you're behind a masquerading NAT (as most home users are these days), there is a limited pool of external ports, and these must be shared among the TCP connections. Therefore masquerading NATs tend to assume a connection has been terminated if no data has been sent for a certain time period.

This and other such issues (anywhere in between the two endpoints) can mean the connection will no longer "work" if you try to send data after a reasonble idle period. However, you may not discover this until you *try* to send data.

Using keepalives both *reduces* the chance of the connection being interrupted somewhere down the line, and also lets you find out about a broken connection sooner.

Comment: Ah! you add a good point here, that is you have to also consider the in-between things that might hinder the operation of a connection such as NAT routers etc...

Comment: This is a good point, and a good reminder that there's more to keep in mind than just what we're directly implementing ourselves. Also, Lemmings!!

Comment: Note that p2p file sharing both chews up a lot of ports and produces a lot of zombie connections, making it more likely that the NAT will need to prune idle connections.

Comment: Not necessarily, a TCP connection is identified by 4 elements: src ip, src port, dest ip, dest port. So you can reuse the same external (source) port as long as the destination ip is different.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I think the real reason is that NATs have a fixed size table of open connections, due to memory constraints and lookup time.

Comment: What's funny is that the TCP keepalive interval is larger than the NAT one by default, at least with some configs. So idle connections may be lost through NATs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some supplemental literature on keepalive which explains it in much finer detail.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO

Since Java does not allow you to control the actual keepalive times, you can use the examples to change them if you're using a Linux kernel (or proc based OS).

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA Socket – TCP connections are managed on the OS level, java.net.Socket does not provide any in-built function to set timeouts for keepalive packet on a per-socket level. But we can enable keepalive option for java socket but it takes 2 hours 11 minutes (7200 sec) by default to process after a stale tcp connections. This cause connection will be availabe for very long time before purge. So we found some solution to use Java Native Interface (JNI) that call native code(c++) to configure these options.

****Windows OS****

In windows operating system keepalive_time & keepalive_intvl can be configurable but tcp_keepalive_probes cannot be change.By default, when a TCP socket is initialized sets the keep-alive timeout to 2 hours and the keep-alive interval to 1 second. The default system-wide value of the keep-alive timeout is controllable through the KeepAliveTime registry setting which takes a value in milliseconds.

On Windows Vista and later, the number of keep-alive probes (data retransmissions) is set to 10 and cannot be changed.

On Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000, the default setting for number of keep-alive probes is 5. The number of keep-alive probes is controllable. For windows Winsock IOCTLs library is used to configure the tcp-keepalive parameters.

```
int WSAIoctl(
    SocketFD, // descriptor identifying a socket
    SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, // dwIoControlCode
    (LPVOID) lpvInBuffer, // pointer to tcp_keepalive struct (DWORD)
    cbInBuffer, // length of input buffer
    NULL, // output buffer
    0, // size of output buffer
    (LPDWORD) lpcbBytesReturned, // number of bytes returned
    NULL, // OVERLAPPED structure
    NULL // completion routine
);
```

**Linux OS**

Linux has built-in support for keepalive which is need to be enabling TCP/IP networking in order to use it. Programs must request keepalive control for their sockets using the setsockopt interface.

int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int optname, const void *optval, socklen_t optlen)

Each client socket will be created using java.net.Socket. File descriptor ID for each socket will retrieve using java reflection.

Comment: 7200 seconds is two hours, which is the minimum default timeout. I don't know where you got the 11 minutes from.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/so-keepalive)

- KeepAliveTime (REG_DWORD, milliseconds, by default is not set which means 7,200,000,000 
  = 2 hours) - analogue to tcp_keepalive_time
- KeepAliveInterval (REG_DWORD, milliseconds, by default is not set which means 1,000 = 1 second) - analogue to tcp_keepalive_intvl
- Since Windows Vista there is no analogue to tcp_keepalive_probes, value is fixed to 10 and cannot be changed

Comment: 7,200,000,000ms is 2000 hours, not 2.

Comment: @Ant No it isn't. You are confusing milliseconds with seconds, and you haven't even got that right.

Comment: @user207421  
7,200,000,000ms / 1000 = 7,200,000s
7,200,000s / 60 = 120,000 mins
120,000 mins / 60 = 2000 hours
Where did I go wrong?