# How to set the keepalive timeout in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, keep-alive

I'd like to lower the TCP keepalive time on a Socket I'm opening from 2 hours to something on the order of ten minutes. I can make it use keepalive with socket.setKeepAlive(true), but how can I control the time before a keepalive packet is sent?

It looks like I could do this if I was using the NDK, but I want to distribute this code as a jar, so that's not ideal for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too obvious an answer [i.e. it's not an option for your specific case] but you can of course implement your own keepalive by sending 1 throw-away byte (in either direction) every 10 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I am probably going to end up doing that. I hear it's more taxing on the battery life to do that, though. I can set the server-side keepalive which hopefully is reasonable.

Answer (score 14):

I think it might be **quite important** to be able to set the **keepalive timeouts** on an **per app** level, especially on a mobile device, because it might be under bad network conditions (wifi/mobile). If the **app does not send (m)any data** but uses a **persistent connection**, the socket **will not detect whether the connection is lost**, unless it sends tcp keepalive probes. Setting this option is usually possible via the [setsockopt(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) call, but the android sdk provides only the `setKeepAlive(boolean)` option. Deeper in the stack, that functions calls [libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptInt(...)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/ForwardingOs.java), which is **not available directly**, nor the required file descriptor. **By using java reflection, setting the keepalive timeouts is possible anyway**, e.g like this:

```
private final static int SOL_TCP = 6;

private final static int TCP_KEEPIDLE = 4;
private final static int TCP_KEEPINTVL = 5;
private final static int TCP_KEEPCNT = 6;

protected void setKeepaliveSocketOptions(Socket socket, int idleTimeout, int interval, int count) {
  try {
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    try {
      Field socketImplField = Class.forName("java.net.Socket").getDeclaredField("impl");
      if(socketImplField != null) {
        socketImplField.setAccessible(true);
        Object plainSocketImpl = socketImplField.get(socket);
        Field fileDescriptorField = Class.forName("java.net.SocketImpl").getDeclaredField("fd");
        if(fileDescriptorField != null) {
          fileDescriptorField.setAccessible(true);
          FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = (FileDescriptor)fileDescriptorField.get(plainSocketImpl);
          Class libCoreClass = Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore");
          Field osField = libCoreClass.getDeclaredField("os");
          osField.setAccessible(true);
          Object libcoreOs = osField.get(libCoreClass);
          Method setSocketOptsMethod = Class.forName("libcore.io.ForwardingOs").getDeclaredMethod("setsockoptInt", FileDescriptor.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);
          if(setSocketOptsMethod != null) {
            setSocketOptsMethod.invoke(libcoreOs, fileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, idleTimeout);
            setSocketOptsMethod.invoke(libcoreOs, fileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval);
            setSocketOptsMethod.invoke(libcoreOs, fileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, count);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception reflectionException) {}
  } catch (SocketException e) {}
}
```

**This works** at least **until** the following **requirements** are met:

- `libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptInt/4` exists at current sdk version
- `java.net.Socket` has an `impl` member at the current sdk version
- `java.net.Socket->impl` is instance of `java.net.SocketImpl` at the current sdk version
- `java.net.SocketImpl` has a `fd` member at the current sdk version
- `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL` and `TCP_KEEPCNT` have the same values
  (`4`, `5` and `6`) at the current sdk version **and** all android devices / architectures.

That seems to be true at least for android versions **from** [**4.0.1** / November 2011](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.0.1_r1) up to **recent version** [**5.1.1** r9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.1.1_r9).

See `luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/Os.java`, `luni/src/main/java/java/net/Socket.java` and `luni/src/main/java/java/net/SocketImpl.java` from the [platform/libcore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/) repository.
`TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL` and `TCP_KEEPCNT` seem to have the same values for android versions since [2.2.3 r2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/android-2.2.3_r2.1) and all architectures. This can be validated e.g. by executing `find . -name tcp.h | xargs grep -ho "TCP_KEEP\w\+\s\+\d\+" | sort | uniq -c` in the [android platform/ndk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk) repository.

Comment: Excellent! I always thought that linux and android might have same settings but these settings fix the issues I have seen in my keep_alive code on Android :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Android is based on Linux, and Linux supports the `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` socket options via the `setsocketopt()` function, which is wrapped by the `java.net.SocketOptions` interface.  `java.net.SocketImpl` implements `SocketOptions`, and `java.net.Socket` wraps a `SocketImpl`.  What I don't know is whether it is possible to access the `SocketImpl` of a given `Socket` object.

What you could try doing is use `Socket.setSocketImplFactory()` to implement your own custom `SocketImplFactory` class, which is responsible for creating `SocketImpl` instances for `Socket` objects.  That way, your factory could call `SocketOptions.setOption()` for `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` for any sockets your app creates.

Comment: +1 for hint for use of TCP_KEEPIDLE and TCP_KEEPINTVL in the case of android. But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1480246/3574669) is voting for implementation of application level not system level keepalive. What is you opinion?

Comment: This question was specifically about system-level keepalive, which every platform supports as it is part of the TCP sec (though not every platform supports setting the interval). Application-level keepalive is dependent on the protocol, and many protocols do not support an application-level keepalive. **IF** an application-level keepalive is possible, by all means use it.  But fall back to system-level keepalive when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into high voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885114/8055779) and reflection restrictions on my Android 10 device i found a working solutions on modern Android APIs.
Firstly, checking the [blocklists](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) of java's sysem methods for restriction `setsockoptInt` on different Android versions i found 4 packages with this method and the only package without block was core Android `android.system.Os` public package. Surprisingly, this package allows to acess low-level system functions without using java reflection directly.

Started from Android 8 (api 26) this package enriched with [`Os.setsockoptInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os#setsockoptInt(java.io.FileDescriptor,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method.
The second, getting `FileDescriptor` of socket can be also more gracefully by casting `SocketInputStream` to a `FileInputStream` as in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456019/8055779).
In result the code that works very well is here:

```
private final static int SOL_TCP = 6;

private final static int TCP_KEEPIDLE = 4;
private final static int TCP_KEEPINTVL = 5;
private final static int TCP_KEEPCNT = 6;

protected void setKeepAliveSocketOptions(Socket socket, int idleTimeout, int interval, int count) {
    try {
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        FileDescriptor socketFileDescriptor = ((FileInputStream)socket.getInputStream()).getFD();
        if (socketFileDescriptor != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Os.setsockoptInt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, idleTimeout);
                Os.setsockoptInt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval);
                Os.setsockoptInt(socketFileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, count);
            } else {
                Class libCoreClass = Class.forName("libcore.io.Libcore");
                Field osField = libCoreClass.getDeclaredField("os");
                osField.setAccessible(true);
                Object libcoreOs = osField.get(libCoreClass);
                Method setSocketOptsMethod = Class.forName("libcore.io.ForwardingOs")
                        .getDeclaredMethod("setsockoptInt", FileDescriptor.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);
                setSocketOptsMethod.invoke(libcoreOs, socketFileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, idleTimeout);
                setSocketOptsMethod.invoke(libcoreOs, socketFileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval);
                setSocketOptsMethod.invoke(libcoreOs, socketFileDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, count);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```