# Most efficient way to pass Java socket file descriptor to C binary file

Tags: java, c, sockets, java-native-interface, file-descriptor

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, I'm trying to obtain a socket in Java, and hand over its file descriptor number so that I can use it in a C binary (the fd would be as argument).

I've obtained the FileDescriptor using reflection... but can't access the actual number anywhere.

I know other people have suggested JNI, but I'd like to keep it within Java if possible (and couldn't fully figure out how to do it)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't and even if you could, I don't see how you could "hand it over to" some other binary? Maybe if you posted what you are actually trying to do, there could be some alternatives?

Comment: I can, just done it and it works like a charm :)

Comment: It's generally meaningless to pass the descriptor number to another process - the same number in the other process doesn't necessarily refer to the same thing.  How many processes on your system are using file descriptor `1` for `stdout` right now?  Is `stdout` the same for all of them?

Comment: I was under the impression that calling the Exec method (Java Runtime) created a child process rather than a completely separate one, which would mean file descriptors would be shared. If that is not the case then I'll have to use JNI and the dup syscall.

Comment: Looks like it does something like a `fork()`/`exec()` (which inherits *copies* of the descriptors from the parent) but also closes everything but `stdin`,`stdout`, and `stderr` in the child.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Java Runtime doesn't support clone (unfortunate for my purpose anyways)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 7, you can cast a `SocketInputStream` to a `FileInputStream`, and call `getFD()` to get the `FileDescriptor` object.

Then you can use reflection to access the FileDescriptor object's `private int fd` field.  (You use the `Class.getDeclaredField(...)` method to get the Field, call `Field.setAccessible(true)`, and then get the field's value using `Field.getInt(...)`.)

---

Beware that you may be making your code platform dependent by doing this.  There are no guarantees that the particular private field will be present in older ... or forth-coming versions of Java, or in implementations of Java done by other vendors / suppliers.

Comment: doesn't really help the OP... and anyways, AFAIK, this doesn't expose the underlying socket fd.

Comment: @Nim - You will have to ask him ... but that is my intention.  And have you looked at the source code before you start making pronouncements that it won't work?  (Hint: I have.)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, I already had the FileDescriptor object, I just needed the fd field, but was looking at a depecrated version of the API (must have been) since it didn't show any private int fd field ... That's the native file descriptor right? If yes then tahanks!

Comment: @user1018513 - you have to look at the source code.  It is a private field, and private fields are not shown in the Java SE javadocs.  I looked at the Java 7 version ... and this may be different in other versions.

Comment: You're right :). Grepcode is my friend from now on. Thanks. And the code is already horridly platform dependent ... but it'll do for now !

Comment: I've got a Socket object that's just been returned from ServerSocketChannel#socket()#accept().  When I call getInputStream() on it and try to cast that to a FileInputStream, I get a ClassCastException that the SocketAdaptor can't be cast: sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.FileInputStream"

Answer (score 1):

Stephen C's answer addresses how to get a `FileDescriptor`, but here's a method to the file descriptor number from that object. On Windows, `FileDescriptor` uses `long handle` instead of `int fd` internally, so this method first checks if `handle` is used and returns that if so, otherwise it falls back to returning `fd`. I haven't tested this with sockets as OP is using, but I imagine `Windows` JVMs still use `handle`.

```
public static long fileno(FileDescriptor fd) throws IOException {
    try {
        if (fd.valid()) {
            // windows builds use long handle
            long fileno = getFileDescriptorField(fd, "handle", false);
            if (fileno != -1) {
                return fileno;
            }
            // unix builds use int fd
            return getFileDescriptorField(fd, "fd", true);
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IOException("unable to access handle/fd fields in FileDescriptor", e);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new IOException("FileDescriptor in this JVM lacks handle/fd fields", e);
    }
    return -1;
}

private static long getFileDescriptorField(FileDescriptor fd, String fieldName, boolean isInt) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    long value = isInt ? field.getInt(fd) : field.getLong(fd);
    field.setAccessible(false);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: ends up in FileDescriptor in this JVM lacks handle/fd field , any other clues ?