# File descriptor for socket.io in Java (android)?

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

I'm creating a program to record the screen and use a socket to send the data over socket to server. I've successfully implemented it on my sdcard but how do I create a socket from Socket.io library? setOutputFile asks for filedescriptor. Where is it in socket.io?

Socket.io code:

```
try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.105:3000");
            socket.connect();
// works

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now for mediarecorder:

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
// ... some more props...
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(NEED A FILE DESCRIPTOR HERE);
```

How do I go about this? Help!

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the file descriptor of a socket using:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket).getFileDescriptor();
```

Source: [android-developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/38Y4L3Sliak)

Comment: ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket needs java.net.Socket, socket.io creates a io.socket.client.Socket. I'm using this dependency for Sockets.io: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Answer (score 0):

Mike Jaren's answer about using ParcelFileDescriptor is no so correct, due to this method creates new file descriptor, reflecting the original.
Working method for Java7+ (which android supports) for getting correct file descriptor of socket:

```
FileDescriptor fd = ((FileInputStream)socket.getInputStream()).getFD();
```

Source: [other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456019/8055779)

Also other method of getting socket's file descriptor on andorid (but complicated) with using java reflection may be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885114/8055779).