# Firebase Read data in background Android

Tags: android, firebase, background, firebase-realtime-database

Is there anyway that I can read the data from the real time database of firebase and can save it while the app is not opened, I am using `Firebase.getInstance.goOnline();` 
in the code whenever Network connectivity changes so that it listens the data.

I am  able to write the data in the database if app is not in recents or is not opened but in the same way I am unable to read the data when app is not opened. Is there any possible way ? Or I am going for an wrong approach ?

I just wants that whenever network connection will be available it will download the updated data automatically. , so that later on I can see the updated data being offline.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Please.

Comment: I'm not sure right now, but there is an onPause() Method you could try.

Comment: I'd recommend against using Firebase Database for background data transfer. Instead use Firebase Cloud Messaging for that. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593510/firebase-listener-effect-on-battery-life-and-cpu/42593885#42593885

Answer (score 1):

Android makes no guarantees about whether or not your app process is running when it's not visible on screen.  It could be killed in favor of other processes that are a higher priority for the user.  So, in general it's not a good idea to assume that you can do networking any time you want.

Also, newer Android devices will go into [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) to help save the user's battery.  In that case, your app will definitely not be running.

If you want to ensure that your app process is running, you can schedule some time with [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) or [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).  Or you can ping your app from your server with [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: I can't get it how I can approach that with the help of above Options