# Will Firebase Realtime Database Sync when the device comes online, But the Application is not opened?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying out Firebase Realtime Database. I have a created a node `users`, In that I have created a node `user_1`. The JSON is like the one below

```
{
  "user_1" : {
    "firstName" : "User",
    "lastName" : "Last",
    "middleName" : "S"
  }
}
```

I have enabled Offline Persistence & the Sync enabled for that particular Node `user_1`.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("user_1").keepSynced(true);
```

Firstly , I opened the App & synched the `user_1` data. Then I killed the Application, But the Device is still connected to internet. I made changes to the `user_1` node in the Firebase Console. After sometime , I have disconnected to internet. I opened the app again, listened to that node `user_1`. But the offline data is not synced with the latest data from Firebase Server. Does that mean , `keepSynced()` will only work when the Application is in Foreground ?

Comment: Yes, because FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() is mapped with your application class and when you kill your application firebase will not get any callback. Please go through to this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html)

Comment: Where are you removing the listener?

Comment: I am removing the Listener in the Application, But from the docs , what i understand , If we use keepSynced(true), then the data should be synced without any listeners

Comment: @AlexMamo `keepSynced(true)` essentially set an empty listener on the reference/query. You'd usually not remove it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand, beeing empty it's not need to be removed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `keepSynced(true)`, the Firebase Realtime Database client synchronizes the data at that location while your app is active.

If you force-kill the app, the client will not be active anymore and it won't synchronize anymore.

It may continue to synchronize for a while when your back goes into the background. Whether it does this and for how long depends on the Android version and device manufacturer. Given their efforts to reduce background data usage (to improve battery life), I'd recommend not relying on this.

Comment: But if I want to listen to the Database change events from Background , is there any way we can achieve it using Firebase Realtime Database ?

Comment: That has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend you check out some of those [previous questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+database+android+background). For example: [Handling keepSynced while on background on Android and with FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42210186) and [Firebase Read data in background Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42606370) seem similar.