# Socket Programing java - how much time socket connection is alive? And how can I control it?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

Do you know how can I keep alive a socket connection if I do not do any actions on the socket?
I just noticed that if my connection is on background and I do not operate it I get this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(Unknown Source)
```

So, how can I control that the connection will not be lost after some idle time and after how much time by default does it happen?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480236/does-a-tcp-socket-connection-have-a-keep-alive

Comment: @KlasLindbäck No it isn't. The immediate problem here is a reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has no general solution.  It is quite likely that the remote server / service that has decided to reset/close the TCP/IP connection.  How and why it decides is application specific.  An application specific solution will be required to prevent it.

FWIW, the SO_KEEP_ALIVE mechanism causes the protocol stack to occasionally exchange messages on an otherwise idle TCP/IP connection.  This may help if you are experiencing resets on a NATed connection due to port reuse.  The relevant Java method is [`Socket.setKeepAlive`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive%28boolean%29).

Comment: okay thanks, do you have any link to the mechanism you specified I may try it, I'm runing my server on ubuntu 10 if thats help.

Comment: any way to control the keepalive timeout length?

Answer (score 1):

> Connection reset by peer: socket write error

This is usually caused by writing to a connection that has already been closed by the peer. It is an application protocol error. You should investigate that first before worrying about connection lifetimes.