# Sockets doesn't send data after a long break 

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, sockets, client

I'm writing a client-server application (client in AS3-AIR, server in C#).

After establishing connection they can transfer files to each other, etc. All good.
However, if the socket connections have a long break (while they are still connected),  connection stops sending data.

It's weird, because the ActionScript socket ".connected" returns `true`. Same for the C# server.
Did anybody face this problem?

Comment: Any NAT router in between that may have timed out? It is generally a bad approach to NOT send regular pings or other informative packets over a TCP socket to make sure both sides are still there.

Comment: How long a break are we talking about? Seconds? Or days? And what actually happens when you try to send? Do you get an error?

Comment: @TomTom That's what Tcp Keep Alive is for;

Comment: POST CODE or would you rather everyone keep guessing?

Comment: what code? Write simple application with tcp sockets on as3 and here the code. Sockets have same behavior at any kind of applications

Comment: @GETah yes, but if the app does not send it you are - at a loss. And I often send sensible small information there. There is a reason a LOT of protocols define a protocol level keep alive signal, for example FIX.

Comment: @user1480049 You can't just write a simple socket connection you are probably losing connection because of the crossdoamin.xml issue but we can not tell because there is no code to look over. I see you are new here but if you have a question it would be best to post all relevant data to your issue this includes server side and client side code. As stated above there are a lot of things going on with a socket connection it is not as simple as writing a simple app with TCP sockets.

Comment: @TomTom That is not true. Keep alive packets are automatically sent by your OS, that is part of the TCP protocol :)

Comment: Ah, NO. Really. Read the spec. They are optional. Plus you do not know the interval - and it may be too long for a device. Plus often you dont want to wait, you want to KNOW something is bad. As I said, learn - read the fix specs, it goes in great detail on the use of this.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480236/does-a-tcp-socket-connection-have-a-keep-alive for more discussion on that. Nice half-knowledge you turn around here. Keepalive standard interval is often way longer than what NAT devices prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sending `ping` (and replying `pong`) every 10 seconds.

Comment: to keep it fresh, the way IRC does it- could send PING [random value] and expect PONG [same value].