# Detecting Socket Disconnect Using TCP KeepAlive

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, ip

I'm developing a server that hosts 3rd party devices over TCP/IP and have been experiencing sudden connection drops (the devices are connecting via cellular).  I need to find a way to detect a disconnect without having to write data to the device itself.

I've looked at using the TCP keepalive functionality but Java doesn't appear to allow any adjustment of the timing of the keepalive operations.

Is there any suggested method for doing this?

My simplified socket code is as follows:

```
public class Test2Socket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket skt = new ServerSocket(1111);

            Socket clientSocket = skt.accept();

            clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);

            System.out.println("Connected..");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you write data to the client? The keepalive interval is usually fixed to 2 hours, so it is not usable to quickly detect dropped connections.

Comment: I tried doing that.  The device just threw an error at me and had something of a hissy fit.

Comment: Have a look at my case and solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31741436/413032

Comment: Spectacularly, a wrong answer is the most voted and accepted solution. It is obvious to me that detecting Socket timeout / network disconnect is the main reason TCP exists. This aspect should not be handled at application level, which is supposed to send NOPs. TCP already sends SYN/ACK packets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will not get far with the built-in keep-alives of the TCP stack. That's because the keep-alive interval cannot be tuned by your application, it is set by the OS, and the defaults are rather high (hours). This is not specific to Java.

If you need to time out in a reasonable time, you have to implement some kind of keep alive in the protocol to be used. Most of the high-level protocols I have seen have some kind of NOP functionality, where you send an "Are you there?" message and the other party sends a "Yes, I'm here" reply without doing anything else.

Comment: The first part of your question is simply not true. Of course there are system calls to set the timers: setsockopt(... TCP_KEEPIDLE ...).

Comment: The proposal in the second part is dangerous and adds complexity to client and server: you mix up levels 4 and 7 here (and must sort out all things manually). TCP gives you what you want to have - why are you doing it again? There are technical solutions - even for Java.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath: I think the original poster would really love to see: a) a link to the documentation about this wonderful system call on Windows, Mac OS X, etc.; b) how to use these from Java, in a portable way.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath Socket options to set per-socket keepalive timers do not exist on all platforms, and not in Java.

Comment: @R.G.: You are missing the point. SO_KEEPALIVE is not good enough.

Comment: The question is about Java, and Java supports read timeouts from TCP sockets on all platforms. Nothing more is required.

Comment: @user207421 Well, you need one more thing: a client sending another request before your read timeout happens. Now how do you coerce the client to send something if it is just not willing to?

Answer (score 4):

For an in-depth discussion of TCP Keep-Alives see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33927447/446554).

But basically TCP Keep-Alives are likely the best method for detecting a stale connection. The main problem is that OS defaults are set at 2 hours before the connection is checked with 11 more minutes of Keep-Alive packets before the connection will actually be dropped.

Don't write your own application-layer Keep Alive protocol when TCP already has it built in. All you have to do is [set the TCP time out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33927447/446554) to something more reasonable like 2-3 minutes.

Unfortunately, since TCP timeouts are managed at the OS level and not from within the JVM, it is difficult (but not impossible) to configure TCP timeouts from within your code on a per-socket basis.

Answer (score 0):

Set a read timeout, with `setSoTimeout(),` to a reasonable value, say double the expected response time, and catch the resulting `SocketTimeoutException.`

NB there is no such thing as "Java TCP KeepAlive".

Answer (score 0):

When you call setKeepalive() on a socket the system parameters (which are tunable) are used.  (Checked it under Debian 8 with openjdk7.)

Because I needed exactly the same functionality, I wrote a small library called [libdontdie](https://github.com/flonatel/libdontdie) that can be preloaded and works with Java.

Answer (score 0):

author of [this](https://github.com/m5c/safesockets) library
here :-)

As has been stated before, unless you rely on difficult-to-configure functionality implemented directly in the TCP protocol (keep-alives), you can hardly detect breakdowns without actually sending data over a connection.

The referenced library encapsulates traditional Java Sockets, while adding easily configurable periodic connectivity checks and ACKing. (Those will stay invisible to the application programmer).
As soon as a breakdown is detected, all inscribed observers will be notified. (Depending on you configuration that can be close to real-time).

The upside is that the lib is rather easy to use (and at least in my own projects works quite reliable).

The downside is, the application layer is not meant to be used for connectivity checks. So basically that lib is using things in a way they are probably not meant to.

Side note:
You mentioned your clients are cellulars. While the linked library *will* work on android, you might have a look at [Push Notification Services](https://www.urbanairship.com/push-notifications-explained) instead of dealing with connectivity issues yourself. That could improve e.g. battery consumption.