# How to detect the server disconnection to the client immediately in Java(Android) socket communication

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on socket programming. Is there any way to detect the server disconnection to the client immediately.

I used socket.isConnected , isBound methods but I did’t get good results.

I tried to read the data from the stream continuously to check but it blocks that if data is not available or return from the server and I don’t want to write garbage data to send each time to check the connection with the server.

Please suggest any suggestions.

Comment: Are you talking about TCP? Or UDP?

Comment: I am talking about TCP socket connection

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which socket type you're using. Even then it is unavoidable to implement a keep-alive mechanism for your specific purpose.

The default TCP keep-alive mechanism checks every 2 hours (!) if the connection still exists. This default value can be changed but it may not work. See:

[Does a TCP socket connection have a "keep alive"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480236/does-a-tcp-socket-connection-have-a-keep-alive)

UDP on the other hand is stateless; there is no connection. The context in which socket.isConnected() should be interpreted is whether it's bound to a local port.

For UDP it is an absolute requirement to send ping/pongs back and forth to determine connectivity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `isConnected()` for UDP doesn't indicate anything about a local port. It indicates whether the socket is connected to a remote address.

Comment: This is untrue... since UDP is stateless there never is a connection with a remote address. 'Connection' in this regard means that the DatagramSocket will simply discard any incoming datagrams from other addresses. Technically there never is a real connection.